# Typescript: enforce prop if another prop present in object

Tags: typescript

How can I enforce the presence of a property when another property in the same object is present?

I am trying to enforce that if a `Period` has a `start` then `end` needs to be present, and vice-versa.

However, in my example `period` ends up as type `Period` even tho it has an `end` property, I'd expected typescript to say  `Property 'start' is missing in type '{ day: 1; end: string; }' but required in type 'FullPeriod'`

```
type DefaultPeriod = {
  day: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7
}

type FullPeriod = DefaultPeriod & {
  start: string
  end: string
}

type Period = DefaultPeriod | FullPeriod

const period: Period = {
  day: 1,
  end: '00:00',
}

type Test = typeof period extends FullPeriod ? true : false // False as expected
type TestB = typeof period extends DefaultPeriod ? true : false // True ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the code is not failing for the `period` constant is because TypeScript will allow extra properties to be specified if they are in other branches of a union.  Therefore, it thinks `period` is a `DefaultPeriod` but it will allow `start` and `end`.  To fix this, you must make the unions discriminated by those properties so they must be all or nothing.  You can easily do this by intersecting your `DefaultPeriod` type with an object type of the keys of `FullPeriod` set to `never` and optional so they **must** not be specified when you are in the `DefaultPeriod` branch.

```
type DefaultPeriod = {
  day: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7;
}

type FullPeriod = DefaultPeriod & {
  start: string
  end: string
}

type Period = (DefaultPeriod & Partial<Record<Exclude<keyof FullPeriod, "day">, never>>) | FullPeriod

// @ts-expect-error ✅ Correctly Fails
const test1: Period = {
  day: 1,
  end: '00:00',
}

// @ts-expect-error ✅ Correctly Fails
const test2: Period = {
  day: 1,
  start: '00:00',
}

// ✅ Correctly Passes
const test3: Period = {
  day: 1,
}
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhBmBDArgG2ABQgJwJYHsATKAXigG8BYAKCikMRAC4oBGKAHygCZOoBmPgBY+AVj4A2PgHYA3DQC+NGqEhQAYmlRY8RUrAQp0OgsQBkFGnQDOwRNmAtbeAHYBzK1AgvCT4K49qJWoVcGgTPTIACjgkNEwcUygLDHtgXERUAB4AJQgAY3xsQiyAUQAPfNRkQggsgGsIEHx4DS0IwgAaKAAiBhAegD5ulwgANxxBwYBKPk1UbUSiZWoAelWoAAFgawBaCHLIfOB97GwiqEBQcigAYSLsAuBUEA1EXFRrGkKXWyhgCFsrBYHX0VFo9EYLFYnU83l8UAA5AAGJFMFEImFBFbrLY7faHR6nc7YK63e6PZ6vd6fajfX7-WzcYFLYhkMF0fpQzE2OwOFjI1HozHBGg4653M4Ul6pazWAFffA-YB-AHAfjM3SsyzgzlsYVAA)